# Configuring ALE plugin with Pylint

Tags: python, django, vim, pylint, neovim

I'm using [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) with Pylint and pylint-django, but I'm not able to configure it. It shows a linter warning while browsing any file within a Django project:

```
no-member: User class has no member objects for below code.
```

on code like the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user_list = User.objects.all()
```

Comment: [I downvoted because lacking a minimal, complete, verifiable example makes it hard to answer.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: @IngoKarkat would this help?

Comment: That's better, thanks! Downvote retracted.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research I found the solution. If you have installed everything correctly including `w0rp's ale`, `pylint` & `pylint-django`. In your `vimrc` add the following line & have fun developing web apps using django.
Thanks.

```
let g:ale_python_pylint_options = '--load-plugins pylint_django'
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler per-project way is to install pylint_django and use a pylintrc file.

```
pip install pylint-django
```

Create a `pylintrc` file:

```
[MASTER]
load-plugins=pylint_django
django-settings-module=myproject.settings
```

Replace `myproject` with your project name.